# What is wrong with a question regarding primary sources of knowledge?

Tags: discussion

> Among the quantitative constraints I mention that the area must be small enough so that the major highlights fit in a single person's head; on the other hand it must be large enough to provide intellectual food for at least a lifetime. (E.W. Dijkstra)

The most important questions in any area are: what are the primary sources of knowledge in this field? How much primary information is there in this area?

These questions are perfectly normal:
"How many words are there in Shakespeare plays/Etruscan language/Bible/...?"
"How many proteins X-Ray structures are known?"
"How many axioms are there in the Set theory?"

Now a question regarding the volume of US federal laws somehow hurts lawyers' feelings: [How many lines of text in all currently active federal laws of US?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22502/how-many-lines-of-text-in-all-currently-active-federal-laws-of-us)

What is wrong  with this question?

Answer (score 3):

### Because it shows a complete lack of understanding of how common law legal systems work

It may be an appropriate question for civil law systems where there is actually a code of laws that can be pointed to and the statement made "Here is the law" although, even there I am doubtful since it would not capture administrative and local law. Common law systems (derived from English law) don't have this - there is the law passed by legislature, administrative law, the law as decided by the courts and the law relating to issues that have not yet been litigated - the last of these are indeterminate - there is definitely a law about it its just that no one knows what it is until it informs a case.

In essence, it is akin to part your second question "How many words are there in ... Etruscan language?" The only sensible answer is "We don't know" - Etruscan is a dead language so we can be definitive about how many Etruscan words have been recovered (at a point in time) but we cannot say how many words there were.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with that question, and in fact I voted it up.  Granted, it touches on [one of my pet interests](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/1196/10).

I surmise from the comments (and other experience talking to practitioners) that there is some resistance among lawyers to drawing analogies between *legal code* and *computer code*.  I might speculate that this is because *law in principle* should be deterministic, but *law in practice* falls abysmally short of that ideal.  And lawyers are embarrassed by and/or tired of explaining that chasm.

Comment: I agree that there's nothing wrong with it, but it's just not very useful, especially in common law systems. The amount of legislation is _possibly_ useful in making _very_ coarse comparisons, but I do have trouble seeing what those comparisons would be.